# angular 2: How to pass a string to a pipe in a Typescript function?

Tags: angular

I want to use 'date' pipe, but I don't want to use it inside HTML template, but inside a Typescript function, something like:

```
dateString.filter(date)
```

Do you have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the date pipe in the component by importing it and then injecting it to your constructor, for example:

```ts
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

this.datePipe.transform(dateString, 'HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 2):

You should inject `DatePipe` inside `providers` array of your `NgModule`  first (As injectables should have been registered in `providers` array) and then you can use `DatePipe` inside your application as injector. You have to call its `transform` function to format date. Inject `DatePipe` it inside `constructor` of your component before using it `DatePipe`

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [..],
   declarations: [..],
   providers: [ DatePipe, ..], //this is very much important line.
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Usage

```
//just for demo, I put filter inside constructor
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe){ datePipe.tranform(date); }
```